# Node Express Unit Test JSON Response

Tags: node.js, express

Just created a new open source middleware project for express. I want to be able to unit test the json response from the routes it generates... Is there anyway I can do this without actually firing up a grunt serve and checking the url?

So goal would be for someway to run the route but instead of sending json to the browser I can store it in a variable / etc...

What the middleware does is generates routes based on annotations in javascript files.

https://github.com/kmgilbert100/annotation-route-loader

I would like to make my unit test include testing the JSON responses you can see in the above url under tests/routes/**/*

Note `app.use(loader)` would load all the routes

Below is the current mocha test

```
// npm modules
const chai = require('chai');
const _ = require('lodash');
const express = require('express');
// local modules
var routeLoader = require('../src/index');
// testing module methods
const assert = chai.assert;

describe('annotation-route-loader', () => {

    // store collection of routes
    var routePaths = [];

    before("Create collection to check from", () => {

        var loader = routeLoader({
            baseUrl: '/',
            path: './routes',
            pattern: '**/*.js',
            params: {
                sports: [
                    'footbal',
                    'baseball',
                    'motocross',
                    'hockey'
                ]
            }
        });

        loader['stack'].forEach( stack => {

            routePaths.push({
                path: stack.route.path,
                methods: stack.route.methods
            })

        })

    });


    it('Should make sure the default path is valid', (done) => {

        // Try And Find Path
        var defaultPath = _.find(routePaths, {path: '/'});
        assert.isObject(defaultPath);
        assert.isTrue(defaultPath.methods.get);

        // Make Callback
        done()

    });


    it('Should make sure the sports path is valid', (done) => {

        // Try And Find Path
        var defaultPath = _.find(routePaths, {path: '/sports'});
        assert.isObject(defaultPath);
        assert.isTrue(defaultPath.methods.get);

        // Make Callback
        done()

    });


    it('Should make sure the sports list path is valid', (done) => {

        // Try And Find Path
        var defaultPath = _.find(routePaths, {path: '/sports/list'});
        assert.isObject(defaultPath);
        assert.isTrue(defaultPath.methods.get);

        // Make Callback
        done()

    });

})
```

Comment: Share some code please. What have you tried? Have you tried using mocks?

Comment: Provided - I've logged out the Router instances / etc cant find anything to help.. have not dug too much into express api tho to see how it handles it

Comment: Take a look at Postman, it has test suite build in, which allow you to test the endpoint/api with predefined json, and the test case can be written in JS.

Comment: Also, take a look at supertest (https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest)

Comment: Supertest is my hero :) ! If you want to put a answer ill select you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments!

https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

Ended up using supertest to get the job done!

See below snippet...

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'tobi' });
});

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '15')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```